# Get selected records in Crystal Reports from SQL Tables

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

This might be a very small question for SQL and Crystal Experts.

For e.g. I have a Table of Names

```
ID    Name
1     John Smith
2     Boris Berker
3     Alex Mathew
4     John Abraham
5     Melisa Estate
6     Willam Schweizer
```

Now in crystal report I just want to display lets say ID-1,4 and 6.

How can I do it. I will get the final IDs to display in C# List. But then how to pass it as parameter to crystal reports.

I use selection formula of crystal reports.

```
{Name.ID}={ID}
```

where {Name.ID} is SQL Column and {ID} is crystal report parameter, but then it would display all the records. Is there a way such that I can pass my list to ID parameter of crystal reports.

I hope I am clear.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in your Crystal Report you will need to amend your parameter to accept multiple values:

[image: Crystal Params]

In your Selection Expert you need to use a formula and have the following:

{OBJECTNAME.COLUMN_NAME} = {?ID}

Then in your C# code you will need to iterate through the C# List and add each value to the Crystal Report parameter using `AddCurrentValue`